# python 2.7 program to extract data from excel workbooks - why does it need to be saved in the same folder as the files?

Tags: python-2.7, directory-structure

I've got a program that uses openpyxl, os and tkinter that lets a person choose a file directory and then extracts data from certain cells from excel files in that directory. As-is, it will only run if the python file is in the same folder as the files from which data is being extracted are located.

I want to make it so that the program file can be stored outside that folder, but I can't figure out why it needs to be within that folder based on my code. Can someone point me to the place in the code that is making this be necessary?

Thank you

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import os
import openpyxl
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog, tkMessageBox, ttk



def file_open():
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
    if file_path == "":
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "No Folder Selected")
    else:
        ALL_SHEETS = [f for f in os.listdir(file_path)
              if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(file_path, f))
              and f.endswith('.xlsx')]
        HEAD = 1
        ROW = 2
        START = 1
        END = 11

        OUTFILE = 'empty_book.xlsx'

        def get_row(sht, start, end, row):
            row_data = []
            for col in range(start, end):
                d = sht.cell(row=row, column=col)
                row_data.append(d.value)
            return row_data


        def get_all(files):
            data_rows = []
            for f in files:
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=f, data_only=True)
                sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Data')
                row = get_row(sheet, START, END, ROW)
                data_rows.append(row)
            return data_rows


        def get_headings(sheets):
            first = sheets[1]
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=first)
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Data')
            row = get_row(sheet, START, END, HEAD)
            return row


        def write_new(header, data, f):
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            ws1 = wb.active
            ws1.title = 'Data'
            ws1.append(header)
            for row in data:
                ws1.append(row)
            wb.save(filename=f)

        def together():
            sheets = sorted(ALL_SHEETS)
            header = get_headings(sheets)
            data = get_all(sheets)
            write_new(header, data, OUTFILE)

        together()

        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Great Job!", "Data Extraction Successful!")


class NSC(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Degree Planner Data Extractor")
        l1 = tk.Label(text="Degree Planner Data Extractor", font=('Segui',         
             20))
        l1.place(x = 35, y = 20)
        nscButton = tk.Button(text=' Extract data from degree planners ',         
                    command=file_open)
        nscButton.place(x= 80, y=100)   
        quitButton = tk.Button(text=" Quit ", command=self.quit)
        quitButton.place(x=155, y=155)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    w = 400
    h = 250
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    root.resizable(0,0)
    app = NSC(root)
    root.mainloop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: That's a lot of code! You could shrink it considerably as an example.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and apologies for that.  I just wasn't sure where in the code the problem originated, so I wanted to include everything just in case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've kinda solved the problem in your code already. `os.listdir` returns file names without path so you needed `os.path.join` for the `isfile` test. You need to add that joined name to your list.

```
    ALL_SHEETS = [os.path.join(file_path, f) for f in os.listdir(file_path)
          if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(file_path, f))
          and f.endswith('.xlsx')]
```

`glob.glob` does almost the same thing with the small risk that somebody named a directory ".xlsx".

```
    from glob import glob
    ALL_SHEETS = [f for f in glob(os.path.join(file_path, "*.xlsx"))
          if os.path.isfile(f)]]
```

Comment: Thank you, tdelaney!  Unfortunately, I tried it with both of your options, and neither will work if the file is saved outside the folder.  They do both work if the file *is* saved in the same folder, though.  Is the problem maybe somewhere else in the code?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: My bad... I forgot to add `file_path` in the `os.path.join` that I added. I've fixed the source.

Comment: That fixed it!  It works perfectly now, thank you very much!